# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias - can´t find the reason

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1248

I'm getting this error:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

the query is:

```
UPDATE rifa
SET maxRifas=(
              (SELECT maxRifas 
               FROM (SELECT * FROM rifa AS crifa)
               WHERE crifa.id=1)
              -1)
WHERE rifa.id=1;
```

help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested queries must be given an alias when used in a FROM.

```
UPDATE rifa 
SET maxRifas=
  (
      (SELECT maxRifas 
       FROM (SELECT * 
             FROM rifa
            ) as crifa 
       WHERE crifa.id=1
      )-1
   )     
WHERE rifa.id=1;
```

Comment: the query : UPDATE rifa
SET maxRifas=(
      (SELECT maxRifas FROM (SELECT * FROM rifa) as crifa WHERE crifa.id=1)-1 thank you :)
   )     
WHERE rifa.id=1;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 UPDATE rifa SET maxRifas= (SELECT (maxRifas - 1) from rifa WHERE id=1)  ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE rifa.id=1)' at line 1

Comment: @echo_me I was just cleaning up his code as a new answer and saw yours and realized, why wasnt I rewriting it???

Comment: i didnt understand you ? you want answer it ?

Comment: i already got this error :/ #1093 - You can't specify target table 'rifa' for update in FROM clause